My team is not responsive to group messages and other group initiatives. What should be the appropriate solution?
So I am a business owner, a managing director of a small company made up of about 5 members. It's small, so I'd imagine communication wouldn't be so much of an issue but it seems that even with a small team like this, everyone is not really responding to things unless I call them or DM them individually. It frustrates me because it's work! Everything is for the good of the company and operations.
I'm paying for a bunch of platforms like Google Workspace to enable cloud sharing and messaging among each other but even with that, nobody seems to care about it. I've tried to enforce using the platform to share files to make it easy for everyone. I've even demonstrated, set up for them, and even bought an entire PC for them all set just to use but they are still ignorant. Everything I set up is being ignored including notion accounts with group database, Google Cloud, WhatsApp groups, calendar events, etc. They are not communicating and responding to any of the initiatives. It's as if it doesn't seem important to them or maybe they feel like their contributions are irrelevant or something. Not even group texts in WhatsApp. I created a group and I'm the only one sending messages in the group. Even though I've asked for confirmation as easily as answering a poll question for people to just pick one, but everyone just ignored it. It's not a silly poll question, its a confirmation of attendance but they don't seem to be taking it seriously.
It feels like I'm doing everything by myself. How should I respond to this? I'm tired and frustrated. If I simply ignore it, the company won't progress and it will die, so I'm the only one that should be worried so it sucks.

When you DM/call someone and finally get a response, do you ask them why they didn't respond to the group chat?

Have you asked 1 or 2 of the more senior team members 1-on-1 what the issue is?  Are these folks in front of a computer all day?  My guess from "bought an entire PC for them" is that they are doing something away from the computer most of the time.  You also listed quite a few different channels for communication.  I'd certainly feel overwhelmed if my boss wanted to interact on half a dozen different platforms.  Particularly if I wasn't sitting at the computer all day.

You don't mention what kind of work your employees are doing, but it does not sound like an office job or anything IT-related. Not since you 'even bought an entire PC for them' - something they obviously didn't need to do the job from the beginning -? The question is: Are they delivering what they are supposed to? Or do your company suffer because you team communication don't work? Have you considered the relevance of your messages? Is it important information about ongoing work, or is it something like an progress update you want from them every half an hour?

I admit I recognise a lot of my own leadership style in this post. I would sometimes implement a policy without clear sanctions for non-compliance, people are not following it, and then I would ... kind of sulk about it and silently drop it. The answer of course is to follow up on new policies - if people are not confirming your meeting requests even though your asked them to, confront them why they didn't. That doesn't have to be a big deal initially, but they do need to know that you noticed and care (in a bad way). If no change in behaviour occurs, escalate your reaction accordingly.

When you say "5 members", to you mean 5 people you hired and pay every month (employees)? Or 5 partners in that business? If the latter, what is their actual involvement (i.e. did they invest funds, did they commit time...)?

And if they are employees, what are they jobs? Your mention "bought an entire PC for them all set just to use" (not sure if that means one PC each or one for all of them), but if their tasks are based on using a computer, then providing each one a PC all set up is not an extra effort on your part, it's part of what they can expect, and if they don't use a PC in their daily work, then they probably just don't look at it. Why would they? Just to see if you sent them a message? I have to admit I'm not quite sure I fully understand your situation.

Also, are you all working in the same office? Remotely? In different countries? Is everybody full time?

Please clarify in your question what negative outcomes you encountered as a result of the group chat/google docs not being used. You mention multiple times nobody uses it, but it is not clear how did this impact your business in terms of product/service delivered to customers. Only then will anyone be able to answer how to apply the tools you have and what to tell your employees.

You might not know about managers schedule vs. makers schedule: https://paulgraham.com/makersschedule.html

@Marcel Excellent point!  And it might link directly in to this question if OP expects near-real-time communication — interrupting their staff, potentially knocking them out of ‘the zone’ and causing major frustration and delay — on matters that could be dealt with ‘offline’ (when each person comes to a natural pause).  Confirmation of attendance is a good example: unless you really need to know immediately (which might be down to bad planning), you should be able to set up a meeting in your calendar system, and then wait for staff to respond in their own time (e.g. within 24h or by EOD).

As a small business in owner in the software business (40+ years), I feel your pain.
Speaking from experience, you are the problem. Whenever there has been a problem with communication in my business it started with me. Own the problem.
To fix the problem, understand what is your goal. What is the simplest way to achieve it. Never forget that "water finds its own level", meaning that if you don't provide an effective solution your team will fudge one up on their own organically. This goes for anything.
People will tend to do what they are measured on. But they also must feel a sense of pride. They aren't ignoring you out of spite, they just aren't getting value out of the tools and protocols you are flinging at them.
First question - Why do you think that they need to communicate to do their jobs effectively? Have a daily stand-up call to review impediments. KEEP IT SHORT.
Second question - Is there documentation lacking that the communication is supposed to provide? Make a simple but formalized punchlist. Note: simple is key.
With five people, collaboration shouldn't be all that hard. Unless timezones are involved, Zoom, teams, google meetings, etc. is more likely the most productive method anyway.

Thank you for this! I am aware that I have to take full responsibility with it and what I was looking for are advice and tips which you have kindly helped with and I really appreciate it. You are absolutely right about having them to feel a sense of pride. That seem to really help with motivation.
To answer some of the missing info, I have been making things simple. For example, I announced in a group chat for attendance on a meeting. All I needed was a yes or a no, but I couldn't get any responses until I had to call them 1 by 1 for confirmation. I must be doing something wrong

@Fargone What has worked for me in the past is when doing the 1 by 1 confirmation calls, after I get the answer I ask what did I do to cause them to be so disrespectful. That usually wakes them up to how to behave. I wish you well.

"Zoom, teams, google meetings" - are you implying that synchronous tools are more productive? In my experience, that only holds for brainstorming or similar, but is almost useless for other 80% of communication. A good ticketing system (e.g. Jira), OTOH, can easily halve that time, removing the need for sync and even async (messages/email) communication to discuss some trivial matters.

@SUTerliakov For a small group where time zone isn't an issue - yes. Face-to-face, even virtual, is productive for a team collaboration. Now - Jira, Github, etc. for tracking work - Of course!! Kicking around ideas and "what if" whiteboarding FOR A SMALL TEAM, IMHO synchronous tools work well. Big teams and multiple time zones, that won't work. Also keep in mind that OP is trying to address a communicate issue. Face-to-Face ensures attention from the team. When the first problem is addressed then they can move forward.

I'm talking exclusively from a small team perspective - I'd hate daily VCS calls with my team for what could be addressed by a simple Slack message or a Jira ticket. That may help solve the insufficient attention problem, but would have made me quit very quickly for another job where my efficiency will be valued. IMO the main problem here is the amount of tooling - I don't see any other excuse for the situation described by OP. For 5 people, something chat-based (but please not Whatsapp! It doesn't play with desktops well) and a ticket tracker should be more than enough.

(to make it clear, I fully agree with the rest of your answer, it's only virtual calls suggestion that makes me cry)

@SUTerliakov  We are on the same page for a functional team. Fixing a broken team is what I am talking about. Think of it as walk before you run. Starting from scratch to get basic communication is different than getting better efficiency. For example: Nobody is to ping me unless they must. Email or other async is perferred in my company. It didn't start out that way.

@Fargone Why do you even need a meeting response if they show up? Meeting confirmation only matters if they miss meetings.

As a member of a 6-person team, I want to throw in my perspective as an addendum. While those in management love to incentivize communication, it's important to know that forcing your team members to communicate every little thing can crush their productivity and, by extension, their morale. Our team used to have huddles and standup meetings every day and sometimes multiple times a day. After a few months of that, a review showed that basically everyone hated it as it was getting in the way of work flows and wasn't providing much benefit, and we've since dialed it back to once every other day.

As a reminder - The OP's issue was with a team that wasn't functioning as desired. When starting out a new team or fixing disfunction that is when sync communications helpful to set guardrails and enforcing expectations is needed. When a team is running well a good leader gets out of the way and relies on async communications and as light of a touch as possible. IMHO in management is to know the when to phase in the difference in operations.

Your post contains several indicators that suggest you need to self-reflect on your approach here. I'm listing them not to argue or persecute, but as an opening for you to self-reflect on what it is you're trying to achieve here. The question, as posted, hints at several failures of leadership on your end that can form the basis for the lack of engagement you're seeing. Enforcing your authority is not the right solution here.
You're the main source of communication, but the question you posted here is a single wall of text with no paragraphs1. It's quite frankly a slog to read, and if this is how you communicate with your employees, they're going to be liable to skip non-essential comms (and might end up missing essential comms because of it).
I could pick at your phrasing of "they are still ignorant", which is going to be an offensive term to use in the workplace, but I suspect you don't converse in English with your employees and this may have been a translation error.
If you do converse in English, or "ignorant" has the same connotations in your language as it does in English, I strongly urge you to reconsider your wording.
You claim to have bought your employees PCs for the purpose of communication, suggesting that these PCs were not required for their job. You make no mention of any training you have given them in using their PCs.
People tend not to broadcast what they don't know how to do, especially after their boss has already enforced them to use a tool and provided no training on it.
"I've tried to enforce [bla] to make it easy for everyone" is a contradiction. If it were easier, people would be using it. The fact that you're needing to enforce it means that people don't want to be using it when you merely suggest it, which suggests that this is not as trivial as you're making it out to be.
You claim that "the company won't progress and it will die" and that "everything is for the good of the company". Taking into account that your employees' work seems to not be PC-centric, and you have not raised any operational problems other than the communication lines you're so desperately trying to enforce, I very much doubt that your company is on the brink of collapse unless people engaged more in the group chat. This is further supported that people are still respond in direct DMs and you aren't particularly complaining about their responses then - you're only fixating on their lack of engagement in a group chat.

It frustrates me because it's work!

You're a managing director of 5 people and you're struggling to talk to them directly? That's concerning. No amount of group chat is going to fix that. If you can barely manage to manage comms with a handful of people, I'm going to call your ability to steer a group conversation into question.

I'm paying for a bunch of platforms like Google Workspace to enable cloud sharing and messaging among each other but even with that, nobody seems to care about it.

You're falling into the trap of "they should use it because I'm paying for it", which is a nonsensical act of micromanagement. Given the amount of tools you're bringing up and the lack of engagement with all of them, it also seems like you've fallen into a "if you build it, they will come" trap.
They should use it because it makes their life easier, not yours (or at least, that is not their motivation to use the tooling). Clearly, it isn't easier for them or they'd be using it. So what have you done to investigate the issue, instead of using your authority to enforce your will?

It's as if it doesn't seem important to them

It's as if you didn't ask them and are merely theorizing about it.
Furthermore, is it? Is this actually important for them in their day to day duties? Or is this important to you, and you implicitly expect you employees to act in your personal best interest? Based on the over- and undertones in this question, I'm guessing it's the latter.

or maybe they feel like their contributions are irrelevant or something.

This statement is dripping with irony through its sheer nonchalance. "Or something" just goes to show exactly how little you care about what your employee's perspective on this issue is. And you still wonder why they'd think their contributions are irrelevant?
The problem you're facing is compounded (if not entirely caused) by you not understanding why no one is proactively engaging with your initiatives and not caring (or something).

This all seems like one big XY problem. You decided what tooling should be used. You decided to enforce this usage. You are now "frustrated and tired" because the tooling isn't used.
At no point did you specify (a) what the problem is you're actually trying to solve, (b) how your employees feel about your proposed solution to that problem, and (c) if there are any other competing solutions that they can offer.
This is a failure of leadership, not of its employees.
So let's engage with the main missing information here, that should have started it all: what are you trying to achieve?  What is a group chat going to solve, if you've already got them responding to DMs?
The only thing that a group chat allows you to do is to infodump public information. This is fine for general public service announcements, but those tend not to need much back and forth in other to be broadcast to everyone (unless someone has further questions that benefit everyone).
If this is the primary source of how your employees receive their work instructions (which seems to be the case since you claim the company will die if they don't start engaging), then you are not managing your employees. You're dumping the information in a pile and expecting them to sort through it for you, on your implicit expectation that everyone will proactively engage with this process for your personal benefit.

1 The original post has since been edited; the paragraphs were not in the first version.

"single wall of text" - I encountered so many questions formatted like this on SE, that this time I did not even notice that it is just a dump of text :) Your answer might be more right than mine...

@virolino, yes I didn't notice either. I suspect what the OP is doing is the computer terminal equivalent of rabbiting on loudly through a megaphone in the office, and assuming that the right person will hear the right thing, rather than engaging directly in dialogue with an appropriate member of his staff, or coordinating the activity of a team of people in an appropriate way.

Firstly, thank you for taking the time for your constructive criticism. Maybe I didn't provide enough information about the situation that created speculations and assumptions. Also, I apologize for being rather informal in my writing and 'wording' on this platform. To clarify, my relationships with my employees are good. My only concern is finding ways to improve my employee's responses as I know I must be doing something wrong. Also, yes. The announcements I made were very important and urgent. That's why I was frustrated.

I have to agree with this. There are about five different communication tools listed in the question. That is one tool for every employee! While some of sort of work planning / logging system might make sense (e.g. a ticket system like Jira, but please, not Jira :-D), I would question why a company that size needs anything else than just talking to each other face-to-face.

About the note on "igorant": I don't know where @Fargone is from but I have often seen it happen in India (as an Indian myself) that someone who ignores something gets termed "ignorant", and the act of ignoring becomes "ignorance". TBH, I find it hard to come up with a suitable word when correcting such uses, maybe "disinterested" or "neglectful" would be more appropriate for the former and, "neglect" is what I usually suggest for the latter.

@muru: Both the adjective and noun would technically be "ignoring" (noun as a gerund) but I wouldn't consider it commonplace to use. Generally speaking I'd expect it to be rephrased as e.g. a lack of response, failing to respond, absence, negligence, ... this hinges on context and tone of conversation.

@Flater I'd agree, but often it's easier to sell a single-word change than a rephrasing - and also more politic, I'd say, since rewriting someone's sentence might make it look like they got the whole thing wrong instead of having just made a poor word choice.

Different angle:
Why should they use them?
Because you want them to...
Yeah, anyone that ever worked with humans before know that this kind of motivation will inevietable fail and/or lead to massive frustration.
Ask yourself:

is the (level and method of) communication that you demand useful to your employee's given or understood tasks
is this usefulness evident to your employees

If any of these two questions gets a "no", then that's your issue.
The amount of money you spend or tools you shove onto them is completely irrelevant. Your core issue is: Your employees do not see the need for the level of communication you want.
It's either you demanding too much or your employees not seeing the necessity. Figure out which of the two (likely both) it is and then work on that. Completely agnostic of any tool or method! Your employees need to see the problem before they will accept the solution (if it even is one) that you propose.
Right now you are proposing/demanding - in their eyes - arbitrary solutions to inexistant or irrelevant problems.
Get on the same page with them about the problem (aka the level of communication necessary), and then suggest or talk about possible solutions.
If your employees are on board about a need for more (group) communication but are still refusing specific proposed solutions (slack for example) talk to them as to why, what they would need for the app to be an - in their eyes - fitting solution to the problem. Do not decide for them (I mean, it could work), your company is 6 people. [the following advice is for after you convinced them that team communication is necessary:] Tell them to propose an app each  or at least list features they'd need in their workflow(s) [all in an email to you maybe with a sentence or two as to why that] and then have a quick meeting discussing the 1-6 proposals (after filtering their suggestions for legal/technical/financial feasibility). Very quick, not much effort for anyone involved and they don't have the instinctive dislike of something being shoved into their face, because they (feel like they) were part of the decision process, that the tool was (partially) their decision / idea.
Give them participation and they will participate.

You stated clearly why you want these applications to be used - they cost you money, you hoped they would save you time.
You speculated as to why your employees do not use them.
I suggest that your next step is to speak to your employees about why they don't use these tools, whether they see any potential use for them as things stand, and what changes would make them useful. Perhaps ask what, if anything, they are currently using to communicate with each other, and why that platform is preferable to the new one. From there, you will have an idea of whether you bought the wrong tools, you failed to train them on the tools, or if you have a different problem.

There is positive reinforcement, and there is negative reinforcement. Carrots and sticks.
In your case, the salaries you pay, and the environment you try to create, are the carrots. Other kinds of carrots would be bonuses for exceptional work. But answering a question is not exceptional work, except in a sanatorium for the mentally challenged.
Now it is the time to chose and use some sticks.
Do not worry. Once you use that stick once or twice, they will understand that you are not joking. Either they will become more cooperative, or they will leave. In the end, you win anyway.

EDIT

The answer was written when some clarifications were not available. In OP's case, the root cause might actually be OP's way of communication, as already explained in other answers.
I worked throughout the years with many kinds of people. The best are obviously the ones who know how to do something and they actually do it. It is OK to work with the people who do NOT know how to do it, but they want to do it - because they are willing to learn, and most often, they actually learn. But it is mostly impossible to work with the people who do not want to cooperate - regardless of their skills, diplomas or competencies. And I wrote my answer from the POV of the latter example.


Losing all your employees is not a win in any business. I don't see why you consider that a win. Especially since from the OP, we have no good example of the low communication  harming their business, only that they believe it might hurt the business in the future. Driving employees away might hurt them right now.

In fields where skilled labor is hard to come by, making the employees leave might pose a risk :)

@mishan: I edited the answer. I am glad to work with people who do not know, but want to work (because sooner or later they learn), rather than be stuck with people who do not want to cooperate in any way. If you do not believe me, please ask my lost health, if you find it ;)

@TomášZato: I think that losing a business is better than losing your health forever. It is much easier to find other people, than finding the lost good health.
